# Añadir columna con conversión de RGB a hexadecimal en pandas empleando una función propia

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un fichero csv donde me da información para cada identificador que color RGB le corresponde, que queda de la siguiente forma:

```
Identificador              RGB
       "1103",      "(0,255,0)"
       "1102",    "(255,255,0)"
       "1101",   "(153,51,153)"
```

Como se puede observar todos los campos son de tipo `string` y sería interesante, que el identificador fuera un entero y RGB una tupla de enteros.

Mi objetivo es añadir una tercera columna al dataframe con la conversión hexadecimal. Para ello tengo una función muy simple que transforma de rgb a hexadecimal y a todo esto le sumo el usar la librería Pandas,

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame, concat

def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb

def getColors():
    # Selecciono fichero y las columnas de interés
    df = read_csv('from/colors.csv')
    df = df[['Identificador','RGB']]

    df['HEX'] = df['RGB'].apply(rgb_to_hex)

def main():
       
    getColors()
    print('FIN')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

El problema viene por lo comentado antes, que RGB es un `string` y yo necesito una tupla. ¿Como se haría?
He probado `df['HEX'] = df['RGB'].apply(tuple(rgb_to_hex))` y sigue dando error.

¿Alguien puede orientarme en que debería hacer?

Muchas gracias y un saludo

**PD:**
Convertir la columna identificador a numérico si sabría, `df["Identificador"] = to_numeric(df["Identificador"])` el problema es la tupla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El comando `eval(cadena)` puede usarse para evaluar lo que hay dentro de una cadena como si fuera una expresión python. En tu caso, si la cadena contiene `"(153,51,153)"` el resultado de `eval()` será la tupla `(153,51,153)`, justo lo que necesitas.

Así que puedes escribir:

```
def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '%02x%02x%02x' % eval(rgb)
```

No obstante esta solución es potencialmente peligrosa si lo que viene en la cadena `rgb` no es la tupla que esperas, sino cualquier otra expresión python. Estarías permitiendo la *inyección de código* (alguien puede preparar un dataframe malintencionado con código en esa columna para que lo ejecutes a través de `eval()`).

Para este caso particular también puedes procesar "a mano" esa cadena, quitándole los paréntesis inicial y final y partiendo por la coma lo que contiene, para convertir seguidamente a entero cada uno de los trozos resultantes. Así:

```
def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '%02x%02x%02x' % (int(color) for color in rgb[1:-1].split(","))
```